# Pass header from Docusign Connect to webhook

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to push notifications from DocuSign Connect to our webhook.

Is there any way to provide a header named Appkey and a given value when DocuSign connect pushes notifications to the provided webhook URL?

Our webhook requires a header named AppKey to access it.

Currently, I don't see any such configuration in Docusign Connect UI.

Answer (score 3):

Drew is correct that custom headers can't be supplied at this time.

A possible workaround: you can supply parameters via the URL's query parameters. Eg use URL `https://docusign-listener.example.com/?appkey=123`

Remember that, thanks to the SSL/TLS protocol, the query parameters are NOT visible to anyone tapping the line since they are only sent after the encrypted channel is set up between the client (DocuSign) and the server (your app).

Also, if you'd like to be able to specify headers for the notification message requests, ask your DocuSign technical contact to add your organization's information to the internal ticket CONNECT-1109. Adding your information will help increase the priority of the enhancement request.

Comment: I know that this feature was not supported back then. Is it supported now? @Larry K

Comment: @bob Not yet, unfortunately. Please ask your DocuSign contacts to add your company information to ticket CONNECT-1109

Answer (score 1):

No, DocuSign Connect doesn't support custom headers.